# How to translate the description, and abstract metatag for the front page in a multilanguage site?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, meta-tags

I am using the metatag module. In admin/config/search/metatags I am controlling my metatags for my front page using Global:Front page. Here it is my configuration

[image: Global:Front Page]

How can I translate these metatags for other language. I can use tokens for the title but I don’t know how to translate the description, and abstract metatag.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution was to install and enable  the [Translation table module](https://drupal.org/project/translation_table). Then follow these steps

1. go to admin/config/regional/translate/translate
2. then filter by metatag and it will show all the metatags that you can translate.

[image: Translation table]
That’s what it worked for me. If you have better solution please add it.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/104829/21602

Solution 2: You can use views to generate front page. To use metateg in views you need to activate metateg views submodule.
7.x-1.1 version of metateg needs to apply patch https://www.drupal.org/node/1986032 for suupport i18n or use 7.x-1.x-dev version.

Answer (score 0):

I use the context module to add meta tags in different languages to any page.

Create a context and select 'Require all conditions'
Add 2 conditions: path and language 
Add 1 reaction: metatag

Configure conditions and reaction